# Pandas- Comparing Rows inside a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to compare rows inside a python groupby and based on a condition perform some action on that rows.

Below is my dataset

| ID | SUBID | billtype | start_date | end_Date | used_bill_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 757911 | 40F8E | Direct | 7/1/2015 | 2/1/2021 | `[]` |
| 757911 | 40F8E | Modern | 3/1/2021 | 8/1/2021 | `["Direct"]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | EA | 7/1/2015 | 8/1/2021 | `[]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | Suites | 4/1/2015 | 7/1/2021 | `["EA"]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | EA RI | 10/1/2019 | 8/1/2021 | `["EA","Suites"]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | EA | 12/1/2017 | 4/1/2018 | `[]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | Direct | 8/1/2018 | 9/1/2020 | `["EA"]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | Modern | 9/1/2020 | 8/1/2021 | `["EA","Direct"]` |

I want to groupby **ID and SUBID**. The **used_bill_type** column contains the bill type used previously  for that **ID and SUBID** combo. So in the 1st row, for **ID -757911 and SUBID -40F8E** having first billing as **Direct** so **used_bill_type** will be empty , while in second row for the same **ID -757911 and SUBID -40F8E**, having second billing type as **Modern**, so its previous **used_bill_type** will be **Direct**.

So i want an output where rows are compared inside the groupby and delete operation is performed on **used_bill_type**

so lets say ,for **ID -757911 and SUBID -40F8E**, **Modern** is added on 3/1/2021 but it's previously added bill type **Direct** ended on 2/1/2021 , so **Direct** should be popped out from the **used_bill_type** list for that row

so when a billing type is added , if its previously added billing type ends before the start_date of this new billing type, then billing type should be removed from the **used_bill_type** list.

so the expected output should be like this:

| ID | SUBID | billtype | start_date | end_Date | used_bill_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 757911 | 40F8E | Direct | 7/1/2015 | 2/1/2021 | `[]` |
| 757911 | 40F8E | Modern | 3/1/2021 | 8/1/2021 | `[]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | EA | 7/1/2015 | 8/1/2021 | `[]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | Suites | 4/1/2017 | 7/1/2021 | `["EA"]` |
| 757911 | D9F83 | EA RI | 10/1/2019 | 8/1/2021 | `["EA","Suites"]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | EA | 12/1/2017 | 4/1/2018 | `[]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | Direct | 8/1/2018 | 9/1/2020 | `[]` |
| 757911 | 6DFB5 | Modern | 9/1/2020 | 8/1/2021 | `["Direct"]` |

Below is the code to create the Dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'TPID' : [757911,757911,757911,757911,757911,77909646,77909646,77909646],
                    'SUBID': ['40F8E','40F8E','D9F83','D9F83','D9F83','6DFB5','6DFB5','6DFB5'],
                   'start_date': ['7/1/2015','3/1/2021','7/1/2015','4/1/2017','10/1/2019','12/1/2017','8/1/2018','9/1/2020'],
                    'end_Date': ['2/1/2021','8/1/2021','8/1/2021','7/1/2021','8/1/2021','4/1/2018','9/1/2020','8/1/2021'],
                    'used_bill_type': [[],["Direct"],[],["EA"],["EA","Suites"],[],["EA"],["EA","Direct"]]
                    })
```

Comment: Does billtype have a specific order? i.e.: `Direct<Modern<EA<Suites<EA RI`
And, does same bills have same start and end date same as your example?

Comment: Hey Babak, No bill don't have any specific order and nor do same bills have same start or end date

Comment: hey Babak, my bad-I have updated the dates in the table. The question would make sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt

```
def billing(sdf):
    btypes = tuple(zip(sdf.billtype, sdf.end_Date))
    sdf.used_bill_type = [
        [btype for btype, edate in btypes[:i] if edate >= sdate]
        for i, sdate in enumerate(sdf.start_date.values)
    ]
    return sdf

df = df.groupby(["TPID", "SUBID"]).apply(billing)
```

which seems to work for the following dataframe (I've added the `'billtype'` column to the sample you've provided)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TPID' : [757911,757911,757911,757911,757911,77909646,77909646,77909646],
    'SUBID': ['40F8E','40F8E','D9F83','D9F83','D9F83','6DFB5','6DFB5','6DFB5'],
    'billtype': ['Direct', 'Modern', 'EA', 'Suites', 'EA RI', 'EA', 'Direct', 'Modern'],
    'start_date': ['7/1/2015','3/1/2021','7/1/2015','4/1/2017','10/1/2019','12/1/2017','8/1/2018','9/1/2020'],
    'end_Date': ['2/1/2021','8/1/2021','8/1/2021','7/1/2021','8/1/2021','4/1/2018','9/1/2020','8/1/2021'],
    'used_bill_type': [[],["Direct"],[],["EA"],["EA","Suites"],[],["EA"],["EA","Direct"]]
})
df.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date)
df.end_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.end_Date)
```

Result:

```
       TPID  SUBID billtype start_date   end_Date used_bill_type
0    757911  40F8E   Direct 2015-07-01 2021-02-01             []
1    757911  40F8E   Modern 2021-03-01 2021-08-01             []
2    757911  D9F83       EA 2015-07-01 2021-08-01             []
3    757911  D9F83   Suites 2017-04-01 2021-07-01           [EA]
4    757911  D9F83    EA RI 2019-10-01 2021-08-01   [EA, Suites]
5  77909646  6DFB5       EA 2017-12-01 2018-04-01             []
6  77909646  6DFB5   Direct 2018-08-01 2020-09-01             []
7  77909646  6DFB5   Modern 2020-09-01 2021-08-01       [Direct]
```

But it feels a bit shaky, because the input has to be in exactly in the right order (especially the `start_date`-column).

Comment: Hey Timus, Thanks a lot the solution worked like a charm. I also learned a bit on List comprehension. Thanks again for sharing this.